# ERROR in src/app/admin/admin.module.ts(83,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-pdf-viewer'

Tags: angular

ERROR in src/app/admin/admin.module.ts(83,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-pdf-viewer'. after installing npm install --save ng2-charts in angular CLI 7.3.10

Answer (score -1):

I think you got error because after install `ng2-charts` the dependencies are update/missing for `ng2-pdf-viewer`

so just run `npm install`